# How to mock System.isFuture()?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, future

I am writing some tests and I have encounter a problem. In my main app I have the following logic:

```
public static void main() {

  if (System.isFuture()) {
    System.debug('Is future');
    // Something
  } else {
    System.debug('Not future');
    // Something else
  }
}
```

My tests currently only test main app synchronously:

```
Test.startTest();
TestClass.main();
Test.stopTest();
```

Tests always output:

> Not future

How do I test other flow? In other words, I need to test methods async way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve that exactely like you solve many other aspects that are hard or impossible to test, like Multicurrency or strange org settings.

1. You let your production code talk to a Facade `SystemFacade.isFuture()` instead
2. The Facade uses a mock during tests

   ```
   public with sharing class SystemFacade {

   @TestVisible
   private static Boolean isFuture = false;

   // PUBLIC

   public static Boolean isFuture() {
       return (Test.isRunningTest()) ? isFuture : System.isFuture();
   }
   ```
3. You set your tests to mock them

```
@IsTest
private static void isFuture() {

    // Setup
    SystemFacade.isFuture = true;


    // Exercise
    main();


    // Verify

}
```

Comment: In fact this facade pattern is so lightweight I often find it better to just include in the service. All you need is the flag, if you initialize to the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

While the other two answers are technically correct, that you can write extra code to somewhat replace the `System.isFuture` invocation during the test, I think you can write code in your test method that runs on both situations.

If your class or method is being called from a scheduled, queueable or batchable context, you can easily test those sync and async in a test method. All those interfaces implement an `execute` method that receives a context object (that is not very much used, to be honest).

To call it synchronously, you can either call that method directly, or call your class' method directly. To test the asynchronous execution, all those interfaces work with `Test.[start|stop]Test` as well.

```
// Async test
MyAsyncCode c = new MyAsyncCode();
Test.startTest();
System.enqueueJob(c);
Test.stopTest();
```

```
// Sync test
MyAsyncCode c = new MyAsyncCode();
Test.startTest();
c.execute(null);
Test.stopTest();
```