# Test Coverage Issue with Site.getSiteId()

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, apextestrunresult

I am unable to cover the below function in test class as `siteId` is always returned null

```
Id siteId = Site.getSiteId();
if (siteId != null) {
  //Community user logic -- THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT COVERED

} else {
  //Non-Community User Logic
}
```

I have tried including `Test.isRunningTest()` but then it causes a problem with the else block being covered...

I have checked the `Site.createPortalUser` documentation and also found similar question for the same : [Known Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96859/site-createportaluser-returning-null-in-test-context)

These are very old threads and was wondering if there were any recents updates to solve this issue now.. Any known solutions or pointers that could help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert Sösemann, I believe you can apply [Facade](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/330290/45062) logic for all Platform methods.

You can just change the return type to **String**, because all Ids are string, but not all strings are ID in apex.

```
public with sharing class SiteFacade {

    @TestVisible
    private static String strSiteId = 'DummySiteId';

    public static String getSiteId(){
        return (Test.isRunningTest()) ? strSiteId : Site.getSiteId();
    }

}
```

and your test will look like this:

```
@IsTest
static void runTest() {
    SiteFacade.strSiteId = 'DummyId';
    test54.testSiteLogic();
    SiteFacade.strSiteId = null;
    test54.testSiteLogic();
}
```

And your class like:

```
public static void testSiteLogic(){
    String siteId = SiteFacade.getSiteId();
    if (siteId != null) {
        System.debug('If- > '+siteId);

    } else {
        System.debug('Else -> '+siteId);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to check if that Id value being used in code does not throw any `System.StringException: Invalid id: DummyId`.

Comment: thanks a lot man!! this solution worked like a charm and it is also re-usable in other components 